# How to add numbers to the keys in dictionary with loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the values from an array of numbers as values in the dictionary/object.

```
const array = [5,4,2,1]
const funct = (arr) => {
  const dict = {}
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {    
    `dict.field${i+1}` = arr[i]
  }
  return console.log(dict);
}

funct(array);
```

I expect to have dict = {field1:5, field2:4, field3:2, field4:1}

How can I do it?

Comment: `dict["field" + (i + 1)] = arr[i]`

Answer (score 0):

Use the [computed property access syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) (aka. bracket notation) to access or set a property of an object:

```js
const array = [5,4,2,1]
const funct = (arr) => {
  const dict = {}
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {    
    dict[`field${i+1}`] = arr[i]
  }
  return console.log(dict);
}

funct(array);
```